# Does apple allow opening links to google maps?

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, maps, mkmapview

In my app, I am trying to display directions between two coordinates. I tried using the MKDirections class but could not get them (I live in India so I guess apple does not have these locations in their database).
The I tried opening the apple maps app to show directions but got the same result.
The best workaround right now appears to open the following URL in safari:

```
    let url = "http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=\(sourceLocation.latitude),\(sourceLocation.longitude)&daddr=\(destinationLocation.latitude),\(destinationLocation.longitude)"

    UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: url)!)
```

It directly opens maps.google.com with directions. It shows the route and directions but asks the user to install the google maps app to get turn-by-turn navigation.
I fear that apple might reject my application for opening a google service. Is this allowed?

Comment: Why don't you ask Apple directly? StackOverflow cannot guarantee a correct answer because this is about Apple' App Store policies and not programming.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is about Apple's App Store policies and not programming as defined in the FAQ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is allowed by Apple. You can see it in many apps: they ask you to choose between other apps like Apple Plan or Google Maps for directions.